# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll' (updated question)

Tags: php, iis-10

I have installed wincache. i followed the link and installed wincache.dll. the link is given below. Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll'?

Before installation the error was. "[03-Jun-2020 12:00:44 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll' (tried: C:\PHP\ext\php_wincache.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\PHP\ext\php_php_wincache.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0"

After Installation iam getting. "[04-Jun-2020 07:40:55 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_wincache.dll' (tried: C:\PHP\ext\php_wincache.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), C:\PHP\ext\php_php_wincache.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0"

This is a laravel application on IIS server. please suggest what to do

The configuration of the system is given.

windows server 2016 standard 64-bit , IIS 10 , wincache-2.0.0.8-dev-7.4-nts-vc15-x86 , php 7.4.4 is installed on the server and laravel version is 5.8. These re the configurations please suggest. –

Comment: Sure i will avoid this next time. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to solve your problem:

1. Unpack the package into some temporary location.
2. Copy the php_wincache.dll file into the PHP extensions folder. Typically this folder is called "ext" and it is located in the same folder with all PHP binary files. For example: C:\Program Files\PHP\ext.
3. Using a text editor, open the php.ini file, which is usually located in the same folder where all PHP binary files are. For example: C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini.
4. Add the following line at the end of the php.ini file: extension = php_wincache.dll.
5. Save and close the php.ini file.
6. Recycle the IIS Application Pools for PHP to pick up the configuration changes. To check that the extension has been enabled, create a file called phpinfo.php with a PHP code that calls phpinfo function.
7. Save the phpinfo.php file in the root folder of a IIS web site that uses PHP, then open a browser and make a request to http://localhost/phpinfo.php. Search within the returned web page for a section called wincache. If the extension is enabled, then the phpinfo output will list the configuration settings provided by the WinCache.

Comment: i followed all the steps present but i don't know phpinfo in IIS server is not showing any wincache.dll. Wincache is visible in extensions and is enabled. any suggestions

Comment: the error is the same i want to ask you if anywhere i need to run composer command. update or install is required or not because iam working on a server with no internet availability so iam unable to run composer update or install

Comment: Same here - I have an almost identical environment as you listed, winchache is installed, php.ini is properly configured and I get the same error.

Comment: Ditto here. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error, despite following all the steps exactly as described in WinCache site and in samwu's answer.

To fix it, I had to download the updated WinCache for the correct PHP version. For me, I was running PHP 7.4, so I went to the [WinCache development site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wincache/files/development/) and downloaded the version for PHP 7.4.

Once I did that and followed the instructions again, it worked.

Comment: Seems Wincache is not available for PHP 8.2.* versions

Comment: Still no Wincache for PHP 8.2.* solution.